# easy switch between different monitor layouts

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, games, steam

I have three monitors with a somewhat exotic layout. Maybe not. The middle one is for instance rotated vertically and in portrait mode. My main monitor to the left is also my 100Hz gaming-monitor.

Anyway, I've been trying to figure out an easy away to switch between having all three monitors on using the correct layout when I work and only my gaming monitor on when I game.

So far I'm stuck with manual configuring them in gnome-settings.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 not using Wayland because Nvidia.

So my question is: how do I go about to setup easy switching between the two monitor-layouts? Preferably with the click of a button. Or even better, when I launch Steam.

Any input that can point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if only the gaming monitor is turned on?

Comment: If the monitors are still detected as connected even when they are turned off, what I would recommend is creating `xrandr scripts` and running them with `gnome shortcuts`. `xrandr scripts` are somewhat specific to systems, so if you choose to go with this, you'll need to post the output of `xrandr` and detect which connection is which monitor in your setup.

Comment: @David nothing bad happens, if that's what you mean. Everything works. Looking for an automated switching solution.

Comment: @EmreTalha thx - will look into it

Comment: Found the solution. Autorandr - https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr